# How to automatically change property value in MongoDB when specific date is reached

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is it possible, when creating a document in mongo db, to set a date in the future, like 30 days from today, and then automatically change an other property of this document, when this date is reached?

For example:

- creating a event document
- setting **eventStart** to **31.12.2020**
- when this **date** (31.12.2020) is reached set the property "**over**" to **true**?

Before 31.12.2020:

{
title: "Silvester Party",
eventStart: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00
over: false
}

After 31.12.2020:

{
title: "Silvester Party",
eventStart: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000+00:00
over: true
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not support a self-update field, that is, a field will not ever update itself without external instructions. So you will need to set up a cronjob that calls an execution to the database to modify the field.

For example, you can create a simple API that updates every field that has the matched date. And you can set up a cronjob to call this API once every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can inbuilt MongoDB [Atlas Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/trigger-types/). You can also use a third-party library like [mongodb-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron) or [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).